# Same story but different start(refer the body of Hyakkimaru)

Tags: dororo

In Dororo(2019), Hyakkimaru is unable to talk because of the demon took part of his body. But in Dororo(1969), Hyakkimaru body is also been taken by the demon but he is able to talk.

Why? I see the story is wrote by the same person(Osamu Tezuka). Isn't Dororo(2019) is a remake version of the old one?

Comment: Is there a 2007 version? I knew there was a 1969 version, but never heard of the 2007 one

Comment: @Pablo is right. There is no 2007 version, at least according to its MAL page. Maybe you mistook that certain 2007 anime for Dororo?

Comment: So... apparently, [Dororo (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dororo_(film)) is a Japanese live-action movie. The question is still valid though as a media comparison between the original manga, the 2007 live-action movie, and the 2019 anime remake.

Comment: Ah, I see. After reading about it, seems like it has other major deviations from the original storyline. Seems to be a common trend on anime/manga live-action adaptations.

Comment: I'm seeing it now. It has several differences. Dororo in one is a kid, in the other almost an adult woman. Hyakkimaru recognizes she's a woman from the start. The way his body parts are created is different. The relation between the monk and Hyakkimaru is different. I guess too much adaptation for the big screen for my taste.

Comment: So... looks like you edited the year from 2007 to 1969. Could you really clarify which version do you want to compare? As of current, your edit may invalidate the current answer for 2007, when you ask for 1969.

Comment: 1969, already edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've just watched. This is just like what happened with many other anime adaptations to the big screen / live action. See Dragon Ball Z into Dragon Ball Evolution for example. They take "creative freedom" when they adapt the story and they change a lot of things. The original creator is mentioned because his story is the base for the adaptation, but the screenwriters are different.

The 2007 live action has a lot of things different to the original anime.

> Dororo is an old teen not a kid like in the anime. Dororo's name is given by Hyakkimaru. This doesnt happen neither iin the 2019 nor in the 1969 anime. The way Hyakkimaru's body is rebuilt by his adoptive father is different.

etc

Comment: Another example of a really drastic change is in Attack on Titan's live-action films. I would not recommend watching this one, especially if you read the manga or watched the anime first.

Comment: Well, just a common case in this industry anime right?